# if i need oparete small web server in my application ,does it recognase as virus?

Tags: c++, desktop, embeddedwebserver

i need to operate smell web server in my application play flash swf files in my embedded browser , this application will be distributed to local users to desktop users 
what is the best way to implement it in desktop application i mean ports / local host ?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to show something in your embedded browser there's no need to set up a local web server, just point it to appropriate local files that will be located in your application's directory (using the file:// protocol).

Comment: i have to,im using distend api that give me flash services 
and it have to be called from server (its youtube Chromeless Player)